# Publish App but not found in Google Play?

Tags: android

I published my application on Google Play at Mar 9, 2014. But now, I can't find my app on Google Play, although in Google Play Console it shows "Status : in Prod". Then, today, Mar 12, 2014, I tried to update version for this app. But I also can not found in Google Play, like version on Mar 9, 2014.
Can give me some reason I must do to publish my app?
[image]

Comment: As per the screen shot,you unpublished the app on 9th March and again published the app today i.e 12th march.So, play store will take around 1 day to publish the app.

Comment: You defined some country or device target in Google Play Dashboard?

Comment: You have to wait until some hours because play store will take around 1 day or take some hours to publish the app.

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas I publish my app at Mar 9, but not found it, i do it before i push new version. This is reasion i update new version. I want to ask why from Mar 9 to Mar 12, i can not find my app although it has status in Pro

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas I have other account on Google Play, and other app in this, it have status in Prod and i can find it on Google Play. So, finally, in Status field, it must in Prod or Published ?

Comment: just relax It takes takes several hours until published app

Answer (score 0):

It takes takes several hours until published app appear in google play. So you need to wait.
Also you can try to find your app using the next url

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your.package.name >

If you are using google play search all apps which have similar words in app name and have more installs than your app will be in the top of search result. So maybe you need to scroll down search result list

Comment: I just published my second app, and my first one took around 2 hours. My second one is now almost 24 hours, and not even the link works :/ . I have the same settings as the first one (except for the information etc...)